# while creating table in SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox System.FormatException :string was not recognised as a valid date time

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

i have googled it on the site but every problem is related to fetch data from the database but in my prob the table is not created

creating a table[image: enter image ![enter image description here]description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13s0C.png)

Comment: Suggest you post an issue here https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create , with exact repro steps, and info about vs version and Toolbox version

Comment: I think this is fixed in the latest preview, which you can download from here: https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/151574

Comment: Please let me know if my fix Works, thanks!

Comment: yep it fix the prob .... you were very helpful thanx

Comment: i have one more problem ... while i running the app :- Error 1 An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
  0 0 
error occurs... can you help!!

Comment: Yes, if you provide more details in a new question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest preview of the Toolbox, which you can download from http://sqlcetoobox.codeplex.com